# Why I can't see Sites link under Resources header in Office 365 Admin Center?

Tags: office-365, central-administration

I have logged in on my company's Office 365 Admin Center and I would like to create a site collection, but I don't see the `link Sites under Resources`.
Why can't I see that while I can perfectly see it on my own Office 365 Admin center which is a development account?

My account at my company's site has Global Administration permission.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have tenant/sharepoint administrator rights to view that. However, if you are SharePoint admin , you can follow the below steps.

Go to the admin center > sharepoint

From Sharepoint create site collection

[image]

And from here create a site collection as below:

[image]

Comment: If you look at my screen I have only `Azure AD` under Admin Center. I don't see the sharepoint link as in your print screen. I see that you are using a different URL to mine: https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home. 

Office365 is very strange.

Comment: Can you construct the url you are using above? Remove the company name and just use a fictional name. I need to see the URL. Thank you.

Comment: https://tenantname-admin.sharepoint.com - if you are able to acess this url ,then you should be a SP admin but if you get access denied then you need SharePoint administrator rights